# Integrating $\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} + \text{div} \ \mathbf{j} = 0$ over any region of space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, physics

I am currently studying *Principles of Optics: Electromagnetic Theory of Propagation, Interference and Diffraction of Light*, 7th edition, by Max Born and Emil Wolf. Chapter **1.1.1 Maxwell's equations** says the following:

> The space and times derivatives of the five vectors are related by *Maxwell's equations*, which hold at every point in whose neighbourhood the physical properties of the medium are continuous:
> $$\text{curl} \ \mathbf{H} - \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{\dot{D}} = \dfrac{4\pi}{c} \mathbf{j}, \tag{1}$$
> $$\text{curl} \ \mathbf{E} + \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{\dot{B}} = 0, \tag{2}$$
> the dot denoting differentiation with respect to time.
> They are supplemented by two scalar relations:
> $$\text{div} \ \mathbf{D} = 4 \pi \rho, \tag{3}$$
> $$\text{div} \ \mathbf{B} = 0 . \tag{4}$$
> Eq. (3) may be regarded as a defining equation for the electric charge density $\rho$ and (4) may be said to imply that no free magnetic poles exist.
> From (1) it follows (since $\text{div} \ \text{curl} \ \equiv 0$) that
> $$\text{div} \ \mathbf{j} = - \dfrac{1}{4\pi} \text{div} \ \mathbf{\dot{D}},$$
> or, using (3),
> $$\dfrac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} + \text{div} \ \mathbf{j} = 0. \tag{5}$$
> By analogy with a similar relation encountered in hydrodynamics, (5) is called the *equation of continuity*. It expresses the fact that the charge is conserved in the neighbourhood of any point, for if one integrates (5) over any region of space, one obtains, with the help of Gauss' theorem,
> $$\dfrac{d}{dt} \int \rho \ dV + \int \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = 0, \tag{6}$$
> the second integral being taken over the surface bounding the region and the first throughout the volume, $\mathbf{n}$ denoting the unit outward normal.

I have a number of questions about going from (5) to (6). Taking the integral of (5), we get

$$\int \dfrac{d \rho}{dt} + \text{div} \ \mathbf{j} \ dV = 0 \\ \Rightarrow \int \dfrac{d \rho}{dt} \ dV + \int \text{div} \ \mathbf{j} \ dV = 0$$

Apparently, we then apply [Gauss's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) (which is equivalent to Green's theorem in 2 dimensions), to the second term. But, [according to the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Generalizations), we are supposed to go from the $n$-dimensional volume integral to the ($n - 1$)-dimensional surface integral, so I don't understand how it is applied in this case. Furthermore, I think I remember from studying analysis that we cannot just interchange the integral and partial derivatives to get $\dfrac{d}{dt} \int \rho$ from $\int \dfrac{d \rho}{dt}$ without satisfying some conditions. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify all of this.

Comment: Regarding the second point, yes there are some technical conditions which need to be satisfied, and for the most part in Physics people usually assume those conditions are already satisfied. I know that if you're integrating over a compact set with smooth boundary (like a ball or ellipsoid or any such "nice 3D solids") then one can apply the divergence theorem, and if all the functions are all $C^1$ (in some larger open set) then it is perfectly valid to interchange the partial derivatives and the integral (Leibniz integral rule). But I'm not sure how far we can weaken the hypotheses.

Comment: For your first point though, I don't see what issue you have with applying the divergence theorem in this case. We take a "nice" set $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^3$, and use $\int_{\Omega} \text{div}(\mathbf{j}) \, dV = \int_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{j\cdot n}\, dS$. Here, the dimension is $n=3$, so $n-1 = 2$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Did I not explain my issue with the second question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Generalizations says that we go from the $n$-dimensional volume integral to the ($n - 1$)-dimensional surface integral. But the textbook goes from $n = 1$ to $n = 1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Read the Wikipedia article: $${\displaystyle \underbrace {\int \cdots \int _{U}} _{n}\nabla \cdot \mathbf {F} \,dV=\underbrace {\oint \cdots \oint _{\partial U}} _{n-1}\mathbf {F} \cdot \mathbf {n} \,dS}$$

Comment: If you're referring to the number of integral signs, that's just notation. Usually people don't actually write out the full number of integral signs (for good reason because it is cumbersome, and also the volume/surface element $dV$ or $dS$ already "tells" you how many integrals are supposed to be there). If you want to be more explicit and write out $3$ and $2$ integral signs in appropriate places, be my guest, I'm just saying that it is common for people to not do so.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, the article has the $n$ and $n - 1$ underneath the integrals, so as to denote the number of integral symbols, so I don't see how my interpretation is incorrect?

Comment: So, for example, if you want to write it as $\frac{d}{dt}\iiint_{\Omega} \rho \, dV + \iint_{\partial \Omega}\mathbf{j\cdot n}\, dS =0$, that's fine as well. Like I said, it's a matter of notation. Though realistically speaking, it's a little unnecessary to emphasize that many integral signs because $dV$ is a 3-dimensional volume element and $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^3$ is a 3D solid, while $dS$ is the 2-dimensional "volume element", i.e the area element, and $\partial\Omega$ is a 2-D object. So I think there are already sufficiently many indications of which dimensional integral each thing is.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Hmm, ok, I understand what you're saying. I guess it doesn't matter for indefinite integration; but, in the case of definite integration, we would need the integral symbols to know the specific region over which we are integrating. This confusion likely stems from how I learned multivariable and vector calculus (I've never seen any mathematicians not display all the integral symbols).

Comment: @ThePointer I assure you such notation is common with mathematicians, too. Have a look at Evans' PDE book - almost all of the integrals are with one integral symbol even though they represent surface, volume, etc integration.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Interesting. Thank you both for the clarification.